# element.css in Angular Directive not updating the element's css

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

So I've written a custom directive to change a user's profile picture when they upload a new one. It watches for a change to the photo url and supposedly sets the element's background image to the new one upon a change.

Everything is working UNTIL the element.css() calls. For some reason, it seems to just be skipping those.

```
    client.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        scope: { profilePhoto: '=myDirective' },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.$watch("profilePhoto",function(newValue,oldValue) {
                console.log(newValue) //This logs the correct value
               var url = newValue;
             if (!url) url = "../img/profile_default.png"
             element.css({
                'background-image': 'url(' + url +')', //never updates
                'background-size': 'cover',
                'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'
             })
            })
        }
    }
});
```

What's going on?

EDIT: Note that the background-image IS set correctly the first time through the code, but when I step through in a debugger, it's as if it's not even executed when the $watch variable changes.

Comment: can you provide a working fiddle?

Comment: I created a [punkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lb9g9937pLsTtkoP1FC8?p=preview) and everything works how it should.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this css code is wrong.
Try this (notice the url parameter):

```
element.css({
    'background-image': 'url("' + url +'")',
    'background-size': 'cover',
    'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'
    })
```

Comment: No dice. Tried and same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to set directly the style object properties :

```
var style = element.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(element);

style.backgroundImage  = 'url("' + url +'")';
style.backgroundSize   = 'cover';
style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
```